# Get start and end date of current week in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, getdate

I am trying to get the Start and End dates of the current week for a table in my Sybase ASE database, and return those dates as variables I can add into an insert call.

Ideally, the function can work simply based on the `getDate()` function. I have tried other methods & looked at other answers, but few are catered specifically towards Sybase syntax. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may need to use `datepart` finding the day of week, `dw` - then roll that into a `dateadd` to get the dates you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following combinations of `datepart` and `dateadd` to find the First and Last days of the week.  May not be the most efficient way to do it, as I'm not much of a SQL dev, but it will work.  Default setting has weeks starting on Sunday and ending on Saturday.

```
declare @dw_number smallint,
        @to_first_dw smallint,
        @to_last_dw smallint,
        @wk_begin_date datetime,
        @wk_end_date datetime,

select @dw_number = datepart(dw,getdate())  //get day of week number

select @to_first_dw = (@dw_number -1) * -1,  //get number of days to subtract to get week start
       @to_last_dw = 7 - @dw_number          //get number of days to add to get week end

select @wk_begin_date = dateadd(dd,@to_first_dw,getdate()),
       @wk_end_date = dateadd(dd,@to_last_dw,getdate())

select @wk_begin_date, @wk_end_date
```